# How to I create a batch operation using AWS S3 .NET SDK AmazonS3ControlClient?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Ive looked almost everywhere online, and cannot for the life of me find a demo using c#

The only model I can find right now is in java here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-examples-java.html#batch-ops-examples-java-create-job

Comment: Have you found an answer?